# iterating through subviews - how to reach to all UI objects

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have created a xib file for my custom `UIView` and loaded my xib into my custom `UIView` with;

```
NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductDetailView" owner:self options:nil];
self = [views objectAtIndex:0];
```

I didn't wanted to define all my subviews as IBOutlets, so instead I thought iterating through subviews would be more appropriate.

```
        for (id subview in self.subviews) {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
                UIView *theView = (UIView*)subview;
                if (theView.tag == 16) {
                    // tag 16 is specific to some UIViews... do stuff
                }
            }
            else if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel*)subview;

                if (theLabel.tag == 21) {
                    // tag 17 is specific to some UILabels... do stuff
                }
                else
                {
                    // no tag... do stuff 
                }

            }
        }
```

I thought this would be more robust, however since `UILabel`s are inherited from `UIView`s, I cannot use this approach. I am aware that changing the if orders can make it work, but its not feeling very good to depend on the order if-clauses

What I am asking is, what would be the most logical approach in such situation? Should I be using `viewWithTag:` function instead of looping through `id` s and casting?

Comment: You can have the [subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class] at 'if' and [subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class] at the 'else if'.

Comment: I know and I stated that, that seems a little hacky. I am trying to figure out a more efficient and reasonable way of doing it.

Comment: How about using `isMemberOfClass` instead of `isKindOfClass`?

Comment: @trojanfoe is right. Another approach would be to utilize `respondsToSelector:`

Comment: Estabilish a rule, like for example, that all outlets with a tag greater or equal than 18 are UILabels.

Comment: @trojanfoe isMemberOfClass seems to work. Please provide this as an answer with a bit more detail and I will mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test the *specific* type of an object then use `isMemberOfClass` rather than `isKindOfClass`, which tests if an object is of the specified class **or** inherits from the specified class.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `IBOutletCollection`. You create an Array of `UILabels` and an Array of `UIViews`

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labels;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *views;
```

All you have to do to use this is create the `@property` above and in IB connect all the labels you want grouped to this collection just as you would for a IBOutlet. WHen you want to iterate through them:

```
for (UILabel *label in self.labels) {
     NSLog(@"labelTag:%i", label.tag);
     // Do what you want with this label
}

for (UIView *view in self.views) {
     NSLog(@"viewTag:%i", view.tag);
     // Do what you want with this view
}
```

Comment: Also this approach could come in handy, can you give more detail about the usage of IBOutletCollection

Comment: I added more detail in my post for you.

Comment: thanks! so whoever suffers from such issue, they can prefer one of two solutions, whichever suits more to their situation.